# Netty source port

Tags: netty

I have netty ClientBootstrap which bind to local port  250 and connected to remote port 2000.
In the same time I have netty ServerBootstrap which listen to local port 250.

Is it appropriate configuration? I'm afraid it can cause some issues with income messages.

Answer (score 0):

if the client and the server run on the same host and use the same port and same address you will see an error while trying to bootstrap.

Comment: I use property reuseAddress = true